# Advanced post Table with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, date, post

i just want to learn how to do something like this in Wordpress,

http://glomacs.com/category/management-leadership

a table that comes from post, where i can add different date and different Venue.

i dont really know how to create the course post that i can add different dates and different Venue,

i have in my mind something like ACF and a plugin called: Search and Filter.

then i can add Venue as tags, but still lost on how to create the different dates.

Answer (score 0):

- To create the post type you will need : [register_post_type()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/)
- ACF is a good idea to create custom fields for dates (date field), venues (select field with predefined values) etc.
- Then to filter you can use [pre_get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) hook in your `functions.php` file.

  ```
  add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpso_pre_get_posts');
  function wpso_pre_get_posts($query) {
      if(is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query() || !is_post_type_archive('YOURPOSTYPE')){
         return $query;
      }

      if(isset($_GET['filter_by']) && $_GET['filter_by'] == 'venue') {
         $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
         $query->set('meta_key', 'venue'); // Should be the same key as your ACF field
         $query->set('order', 'DESC');
      }

      return $query;
  }
  ```

On your archive page (`archive-YOURPOSTTYPE.php`) you then just have to display a link to filter like this :

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link('YOURPOSTYPE'); ?>?filter_by=venue">Filter by venues</a>
```

---

Venues could also be a taxonomy instead of ACF field. See [register_taxonomy](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/).
(It also allows you to create a venues archive page)

Comment: Big thanks for this detailed quastion, i think its so hard for me for now, i should learn more, is there any plugin or a theme that has these type of function ready to use ?

and one more thing, what shall i do if i want to change the whole dates, for example at the begining of 2021 i will have to change all the dates, can i do some link between table press mayber, or 
can i do all that table using table press liked to post, i am so sorry for all these quastionm but i am a bit lost :(

Comment: can i hire you to fix it for me ?
how much it cost ?
big thanks :)

Comment: Hi again Alexis, 

i found this theme, where they do excatly as what i want, course in a table, same what you explain above

http://university.cactusthemes.com/shortcode-demo/course-list-table-2/

and this is how it looks inside the admin panel ( https://ibb.co/rfdvMjn ) where you add your duration and id and so on, as what you can see in the table link (post to table). can you please tell me how to change the taxonomy name, and select what to show in the table ?.   Big thanks again :)